# how to lazy load images from URI not from URL in android

Tags: android, contacts

I have a scenario where I need to display contact list  in my app. I am able to get name,phone,email etc.
I am also getting imageuri for contact's  photo.  So, how to lazy load images from URI rather than  traditional URL lazy loading of images.

My URI for some contact is below:

```
 content://com.android.contacts/contacts/400
```

Can any help me in finding a way in which  I can lazyload the images from URI.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just have a look on this [https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader], it supports all types of lazy image loading

Comment: That link is not working

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/ this is another option to load images

Comment: And Aquery is another option :)